# How to make Django form Field Unique?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, unique-constraint

I have a Signup form Where I want to make data of email and mobile Number Field to be Unique....

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.', unique=True)
    mobile_no = forms.CharField(validators=[max_length=17, initial='+91', unique=True)
```

I am Currently using `unique=True` but it raise Error as...

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unique'
```

Comment: I guess you need to specify this in model and have a custom validation in form

Comment: The argument 'unique' works on the model. Link to the docs: [unique](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#unique)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Easiest and fastest way(both for you and server) is to implement it in your model by setting `unique=True`.
If you want it in form anyway you need to override clean

Cleaning email:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    ...

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return email
```

Now `form.is_valid()` will throw error if an user account with given email already exists.
I think you can figure out how to do same thing for mobile number now.

Comment: This does not work for change forms since it will throw an error because it might already exists (e.g. in the case where it was not changed).